# PHP get change nav links

Tags: php, get, include

I have index.php page witch include another page according clicked link:

```
 <a href="index.php?page=somepage">Some Page</a>
```

Or include page "uvod.php" if PAGE is not defined:

```
if(empty($_GET["page"])) include "uvod.php";
else include $_GET["page"].".php";
```

Now, I would like to change navigation links at index.php according to page, which is displayed (included):

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
if ($page="profil") {$link1="PROFIL"; $link2="<li><a href=\"?page=pridatbeh\">Prida&#357; beh</a></li>";}
elseif ($page="pridatbeh") {$link1="PRIDA&#356; BEH"; $link2="<li><a href=\"?page=profil\">Profil</a></li>";}
}
```

BUT ... it does not work. 
$link1=Profil and $link2=first defined link and it's never mind what link I clicked.
I'm sorry that I again distrubing you, but I really don't have idea what I made wrong.

Comment: `$page="profil"` is an _assignment_, not a _comparison_ ...

Comment: to check the condition you have to use == not = ( which is assignment). Use $page=="profil"

Comment: Aside from your problem: You should never rely on user input / url query parameters to include files without checking that the files are ok to be displayed. Otherwise, `index.php?page=../path/to/your/ultra/secret/password/file` will be output to anyone who might know or just try out that path.